# Is there an alignment between Giza pyramid complex and Orion's Belt?

Tags: history, egypt, pyramids

The following pictures which are circulating online:

[image: Orion's belt]
[image: Giza pyramid complex and Orion's belt]
[image: correlation between Giza pyramid complex and Orion's belt]

<sup>There is no original source of these images which I could found, but you can try reverse image lookup to find the copies of it.</sup>

Are these pictures genuinely correct in terms of the visible correlation?
Is the Giza pyramid complex aligned with Orion's Belt?

Comment: even if it were now (and with enough scaling and twisting a picture I'm sure you can make it fit) when the pyramids were built the constellations looked quite different, something the new age hippies never take into consideration making their magical claims.

Comment: It's a valid question. I see nothing shocking in human art imitating nature. Of course, we need some form of historical evidence to show it's not a simple coincidence...

Comment: Some people are easy to impress, I guess.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_correlation_theory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 3 stars in Orion's belt are [in one line and very nearly equally spaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Orion_Belt.jpg), as are the 3 pyramids. The first is a coincidence. The second may be as well, or it could be deliberate because the Egyptians liked it that way. Either way, the "correlation" is meaningless. Of course, the actual distance between the stars on the celestial globe is totally different from the distance between the pyramids; all you need to do is to change the enlargement of the photo to make it match. And, of course, the real distance between the stars in 3D space bears very little relation to the display in the sky.

As for the fact that the have aligned the 3 stars with the pyramids, that is just a matter of turning the photo the right way. The actual Orion's Belt in the sky [will turn as the night progresses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNjMzAnZbtU) (like all stars it goes around the Pole Star once every 24 hours). As the seasons change it will also move up and down in the sky. All this means that the display in the sky bears no relation to the pyramids alignment: it varies from minute to minute.

In summary, there is no evidence that this supposed alignment is in any way special. It's simply a matter of aligning 2 photos in the right way.

I might add that there is also some evidence that the Great Pyramid was [aligned with the celestial north pole](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/gem-projects/hm/0102-1-pyramids/page1002.htm). However, the Pole Star was not in that position when the pyramid was built, because the earth's rotation axis sweeps around in a circle over 26,000 years. This is called the "[precession of the equinoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession)", and 4500 years (the age of the pyramids) is an appreciable fraction of 26,000.

EDIT

The Egyptian god [Osiris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osiris) was associated with annual cycles, such as the flooding of the Nile and the movement of stars. This in turn was linked to the Orion constellation, and the Dog Star (Sirius). As a result, it is conceivable that they intended the alignment of the pyramids to reflect Orion's Belt. By similar reasoning, the Seven Sisters (the Pleiades) are very important in Australian [Aboriginal Dreamtime stories](https://japingkaaboriginalart.com/articles/star-dreaming-seven-sisters/). In both cases the only implied significance is that people of ancient cultures were interested in the sky, and wove it into their myths.

Comment: I'll have to double check this, but association between the Orion belt stars and Osiris wasn't until after the pyramids were built.